# Limit Decimal Places in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I'm using an EditText Field where the user can specify an amount of money.

I set the inputType to numberDecimal which works fine, except that this allows to enter numbers such as 123.122 which is not perfect for money.

I wrote some custom InputFilter method and  it's working like this .User can 5 elements before dot and after dot-two,but not working correctly
My goals are :

1) use should input maximum 9999.99

2) If user starting from 0 and second element is also 0,It must replace with .(for example 0.0) and after two elements after dot(like this 0.01)
here is a my code

```
 public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;
    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]*" + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]*" + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);
        if(!matcher.matches())
            return "";
        return null;
    }

}
```

I'm calling this method like this

```
amountValue.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(5,2)});
```

How I can rewrite my code to solved my issues ?
thanks

Comment: *"second alemen"* What's an "alemen"?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructed regex is all wrong.

The first part of your regex is this expression:

```java
"[0-9]*" + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+"
```

Say `digitsBeforeZero = 5`, that gets you:

```regex
[0-9]*4}+
```

That's not the correct regex. The regex is supposed to be:

```regex
[0-9]{1,5}
```

meaning between 1 and 5 digits.

Comment: Did you write correct regex ? I searched it and used google, just @Andreas

Comment: is it a correct ? Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,5}*4}+" + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{1,5}*4}+" + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?") @Andreas

Comment: @BekaKK Yes, `[0-9]{1,5}` is correct regex. See e.g. javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) *("`X{n,m}` where `X` repeats at least `n` but not more than `m` times")*, or section "Limiting Repetition" on [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) *("The syntax is `{min,max}`")*.

Comment: @BekaKK No, that is not correct regex. What do you believe `X*4}+` means, and why do you believe that? --- It means: *Match character `X` zero or more times, then match character `4`, then match character `}` one or more times*. --- Or it might reject the regex, since `}` is technically a special pattern character, but only in conjunction with `{`, so Java's regex engine allows it.